# Install SDL2 on Mac M1

Tags: c++, sdl

How can I fix this error when I try to compile code containing SDL2 library? I'm a beginner.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in sdl-8efd30.o
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      _main in sdl-8efd30.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in sdl-8efd30.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You need to link to the sdl libraries

Comment: can you show me how to do it in detail? On Clion or VsCode

Comment: Why did you revert my fixes to your formatting? How are you building the code? Have you tried linking the SDL libraries? Have you built the SDL libraries?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how to link sdl libraries in Clion and Vscode on Mac M1. I search Google but there are no answers. I finished installing SDL but cannot compile it. Hope you to help me this issues.

Comment: How are you building the code?

Comment: https://github.com/ducanh272/sdltest/blob/main/main.cpp

Comment: That's your source code, how are you building it?

Comment: I use Vscode to build it and have above errors. In Clion it warned not found SDL2/SDL.h

Comment: visual studio code is basically just a text editor, how are you making it build the code? I'm guessing you've installed a plugin?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new so I haven't understood your question yet. Could you explain in more detail?

Comment: you must be running some kind of command to compile the code? How are you doing that? What command are you running?

Comment: sorry but i don't know to choose which commands for running. I only write code on vscode and clion and those ides will build code for me

Comment: vs code doesn't build c++ on its own, you must have installed a plugin or configured a build task

Comment: hmm i only install extensions and hit the button Run

Comment: ok, which extensions, one of them must be providing your run button

Comment: code runner and c/c++

Comment: code runner is OK for building simple single project files with no dependencies but for anything more complicated you should use a proper build system like cmake or meson. If you want to continue using code runner see the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) and the documentation of your compiler for how to link libraries

Comment: why i can't find information about linking libraries in that document?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#linker-flags